# Save multiple queries to sql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to save multiple queries into a database on two different tables.  Below is the code that I have tried to no avail.  firsttable.a is the same as secondtable.id, con holds the connection info, and everything saves perfectly with one query.  Is there something I am missing here?

```
if(empty($id)){
$uuid = uniqid();
$query = "INSERT INTO firsttable (`id`, `a`, `b`, `uuid`) VALUES (NULL, '$a', '$b', '$uuid')";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO secondtable (`id`, `c`, `d`, `uuid`) VALUES (NULL, '$c', '$d', '$uuid')";
}else{
$query = "UPDATE `firsttable` SET `id` = '$id', `a` = '$a', `b` = '$b', `uuid` = '$uuid' WHERE `id` = $id";

$query2 = "Update INTO secondtable SET `id` = '$a', `c` = '$c', `d` = '$d',

if(!mysqli_multi_query($this->_con, $query;$query2)){
                    throw new Exception(  mysqli_error($this->_con) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql_multi_query](http://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query) takes two arguments: the database connection, and a single string.

You need to concatenate your two queries together as a string:

```
mysqli_multi_query($this->con, $query1 . ';' . $query2);
```

or what you were probably trying to do:

```
mysqli_multi_query($this->con, "$query1;$query2");
```

From the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query) on how to retrieve the result sets for the subsequent queries:

> To retrieve the resultset from the first query you can use `mysqli_use_result()` or `mysqli_store_result()`. All subsequent query results can be processed using `mysqli_more_results()` and `mysqli_next_result()`.

The first example shows how it all works.

In your example, though, the correct syntax is `UPDATE tablename ...`, not `UPDATE INTO tablename ...`.

Comment: w3schools screwed me, they said to simply seperate with a semicolon, not concatenate with the semicolon seperated.  Now it does not kill the page, but still does not save to the database - is there a way to output an error saying why the 2nd query update does not work? Also, I never want to insert into table 2, only update existing data, can I change INSERT for table 2 into just update and have it still work?

Comment: @Steven Updated the answer, which should be what you need. And if you want to only update existing data, and never add anything new, then yes, changing your insert to a valid update query should still work.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Guess I need to use the documentation more, instead of a third party website ;D